# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple representations of the same entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Welcome!

I have seen the same question, but the solutions didn't help me.

The problem occurs when I'm trying to add another visit to dentist. 
I added hashCode and equals method but it didn't help.
Removing cascadeType.MERGE from Visit didn't help too. 
I can't remove cascadeType.MERGE from dentist because then occurs the other problem, that visit must exist before adding it to dentist.

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple representations of the same entity [com.virtualdent.entity.Visit#1] are being merged. Detached: [Visit [id=1, day=asd, time=999]]; Detached: [Visit [id=1, day=Monday, time=12]]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [com.virtualdent.entity.Visit#1] are being merged. Detached: [Visit [id=1, day=asd, time=999]]; Detached: [Visit [id=1, day=Monday, time=12]]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1013)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


Root Cause
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple representations of the same entity [com.virtualdent.entity.Visit#1] are being merged. Detached: [Visit [id=1, day=asd, time=999]]; Detached: [Visit [id=1, day=Monday, time=12]]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [com.virtualdent.entity.Visit#1] are being merged. Detached: [Visit [id=1, day=asd, time=999]]; Detached: [Visit [id=1, day=Monday, time=12]]
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:370)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.save(Unknown Source)
    com.virtualdent.service.DentistServiceImpl.saveDentist(DentistServiceImpl.java:32)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.saveDentist(Unknown Source)
    com.virtualdent.controller.DentistController.saveVisit(DentistController.java:63)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


Root Cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [com.virtualdent.entity.Visit#1] are being merged. Detached: [Visit [id=1, day=asd, time=999]]; Detached: [Visit [id=1, day=Monday, time=12]]
    org.hibernate.event.internal.EntityCopyNotAllowedObserver.entityCopyDetected(EntityCopyNotAllowedObserver.java:45)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.MergeContext.put(MergeContext.java:245)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:285)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:151)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:927)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:897)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:261)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:490)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:415)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:216)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:523)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:455)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:418)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:216)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:149)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.cascadeOnMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:441)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:307)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:151)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:65)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:905)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:891)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.merge(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:492)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.save(Unknown Source)
    com.virtualdent.service.DentistServiceImpl.saveDentist(DentistServiceImpl.java:32)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.saveDentist(Unknown Source)
    com.virtualdent.controller.DentistController.saveVisit(DentistController.java:63)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

My class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="dentysta")
public class Dentist implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3128830699411486597L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @Column
    private String specialization;

    @Column
    private int number;

    @Column
    private String address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="dentist",cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Patient>patients;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="dentists", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Visit>visits;

    public Dentist() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getSpecialization() {
        return specialization;
    }

    public void setSpecialization(String specialization) {
        this.specialization = specialization;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


    public List<Patient> getPatients() {
        return patients;
    }


    public void setPatients(List<Patient> patients) {
        this.patients = patients;
    }



    public List<Visit> getVisits() {
        return visits;
    }

    public void setVisits(List<Visit> visits) {
        this.visits = visits;
    }

    public void addPatient(Patient patient)
    {
        System.out.println("DENTIST=PATIENT+ADDER");

        if(patients==null) {
        patients=new ArrayList<>();
        }

        patient.setDentist(this);
        patients.add(patient);
    }

    public void addVisit(Visit visit)
    {
        if(visits==null)
        {
            visits=new ArrayList<>();
        }
        visit.addDentist(this);
        visits.add(visit);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((address == null) ? 0 : address.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + number;
        result = prime * result + ((patients == null) ? 0 : patients.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((specialization == null) ? 0 : specialization.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((visits == null) ? 0 : visits.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Dentist other = (Dentist) obj;
        if (address == null) {
            if (other.address != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!address.equals(other.address))
            return false;
        if (firstName == null) {
            if (other.firstName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
            return false;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (lastName == null) {
            if (other.lastName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
            return false;
        if (number != other.number)
            return false;
        if (patients == null) {
            if (other.patients != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!patients.equals(other.patients))
            return false;
        if (specialization == null) {
            if (other.specialization != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!specialization.equals(other.specialization))
            return false;
        if (visits == null) {
            if (other.visits != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!visits.equals(other.visits))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name="wizyta")
public class Visit implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -135088128548004469L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String day;

    @Column
    private String time;

    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Dentist>dentists;

    public Visit() {}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public List<Dentist> getDentists() {
        return dentists;
    }

    public void setDentists(List<Dentist> dentists) {
        this.dentists = dentists;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Visit [id=" + id + ", day=" + day + ", time=" + time +"]";
    }


    public void addDentist(Dentist dentist)
    {
        if(dentists==null)
        {
            dentists=new ArrayList<>();
        }
        dentists.add(dentist);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((day == null) ? 0 : day.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((dentists == null) ? 0 : dentists.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((time == null) ? 0 : time.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Visit other = (Visit) obj;
        if (day == null) {
            if (other.day != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!day.equals(other.day))
            return false;
        if (dentists == null) {
            if (other.dentists != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dentists.equals(other.dentists))
            return false;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (time == null) {
            if (other.time != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!time.equals(other.time))
            return false;
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: please share the solutions you've tried so far

Comment: @JakubLicznerski I have tried the solutions from this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591521/java-lang-illegalstateexception-multiple-representations-of-the-same-entity-wit

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use primitives for identifier fields (int, long, etc.)
A procedure on the creation of the new entity, for example, Visit:

- create the new object: `Visit visit = new Visit()` (with primitive `int` visit's id field is filled with `0`)
- if `id` is not `null`, strategy IDENTITY for MySQL will auto-increment `id` and it will be `1`
- filling next fields

Second Visit object:

- create the new object ... and its `id` field again will be `0`
- strategy IDENTITY auto-increments it and it will be `1` again
- etc.

If you set a unique flag, you would get an exception on creating the second object.
Use Long, Integer, String or another type field for an identifier (for all fields also better to use non-primitive types because entity is always created with no-arguments constructor).

Comment: Thank you, it is very valuable information, I didn't realize it, but the error is still the same.

Comment: Okay, i changed the strategy of GeneratedValue and then it is working. Merry Christmas!