# Why spring data jpa-java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity in OneToMany relationship?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working a very small application which contains 3 entity classes.

**1**.Category.
**2**.Products.
**3**.User

**Relationships:-**

**a.** OneToMany between User and Products.

**b.** OneToMany and ManyToOne between category and products i.e. a category can have multiple products and  multiple products can belong to same category.

**Entity Classes are shown below:-**

**User Entity:-**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Products> products;
    //getter and setter
}
```

**Products Entity:-**

```
@Entity
public class Products {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String productname;
    private String cost;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST},
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Category category;
    //getter and setters
}
```

**Category Entity:-**

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category",
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Products> products;
    //getter and setters
}
```

**Method to merge User with products in data base:-**

```
@GetMapping("/cart")
    public String Cart(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("cart",productsSet);
        System.out.println(productsSet);//At this stage in console I am able to see products added in set
        User user = userRepository.findById(1);//hard coded for now.
        user.setProducts(productsSet);
        userService.saveUserProducts(user);//saveUserProducts() method in shown below.
        productsSet.clear();
        return "mycart";
    }
```

**saveUserProducts() :-**

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveUserProducts(User user) {
        entityManager.merge(user);
    }
```

*But when I am running the program I see the following exception in console:-*

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [com.demo.shopping.com.Entity.Products#2] are being merged. Detached: [Products{id=2, productname='p2', cost='200'}]; Detached: [Products{id=2, productname='p2', cost='200'}]
```

I found an article on stack-overflow but it was not fit in my situation.([java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity with @ManyToMany 3 entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591521/java-lang-illegalstateexception-multiple-representations-of-the-same-entity-wit)).Except this I don't get any relevant thing.

Please help me to let me know how to deal with this situation. Hope someone will help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove CascadeType.MERGE user class because in my program I am not adding new products also except this I am creating relation between existing user and products.